# Picking right wso2 wso2mi Image for Kubernetes deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I am having an application developed with wso2esb 4.9.0.zip.
Now to containerize this application we have chosen wso2mi as this module alone solves our purpose.

Considered wso2mi 4.0.0 docker image. We are able to bring our application running with this image. Found few issues

1. While sending SOAP request to third party(which accepts with soap security header) it fails with "creation time is ahead of current time".
   This might be happening because the security header preparation uses DateTimeFormatter of Java 11 as this image comes with Java11 and the target system uses Java 8. May be this causing the failure.

   `String createdDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(Instant.now());`
2. How do i know which docker image has Java 8, so that i may avoid above issue.
3. My requirement is to pick wso2mi with CentoOS 7.9

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 MI is shipped with Java 11. So, if you are in need to change the version, you have to build a new image. You can use the existing `Dockerfile` and modify it up to your requirement, or you can use the existing image and build another image on top of that with the changes in the environment.

For reference, [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/tree/v4.0.0/distribution/src/docker-distribution) is the Dockerfile used to build the `wso2/wso2mi` images.

---

Descriptive instructions for a similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68173055/10269117).