# Can we change the Java version in wso2/wso2mi Docker image?

Tags: java, docker, soap, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

In [wso2/wso2mi](https://hub.docker.com/layers/wso2/wso2mi/4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-centos/images/sha256-1a90f263c8e856ae62a82389228e5028799ab0a0bf0d11272bbcc924029067bf?context=explore) Docker image currently using `ENV JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.10+9`, is this possible to downgrade or upgrade this Java version?

Why am I looking for this?

I am facing a weird problem with `ENV JAVA_VERSION=jdk-11.0.10+9` in my application our SOAP web services throwing

```
{
    "httpCode": 502,
    "userMessage": "Invalid response from remote host",
    "developerMessage": "The creation time is ahead of the current time.",
    "details": {
        "detail": "wsse:InvalidSecurityToken"
    },
    "errorCode": "S:Sender",
    "timeStamp": 1624875331996,
    "transactionId": "CIP-urn:uuid:b813c0a1-da6a-4dfe-8647-7237f39de941"
}
```

While same code is working fine when we are using lower[`1.2.0-centos7`] version of  `wso2/wso2mi` so I want to test `wso2/wso2mi` with different Java version .

Not sure if this code doing some magic for different java version .

```
 private void addSecurityHeader(MessageContext mc, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        SecureRandom rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[16];
        rand.nextBytes(nonceBytes);

        String createdDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).format(Instant.now());
        byte[] createdDateBytes = createdDate.getBytes();

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stream.write(nonceBytes);
        stream.write(createdDateBytes);
        stream.write(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] passwordDigest = md.digest(stream.toByteArray());

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = mc.getEnvelope();
        OMFactory factory = envelope.getOMFactory();

        OMNamespace securityNamespace = factory.createOMNamespace(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "wsse");

        SOAPHeaderBlock securityBlock = envelope.getHeader().addHeaderBlock("Security", securityNamespace);
        securityBlock.setMustUnderstand(true);

        OMElement usernameTokenElement = factory.createOMElement("UsernameToken", securityNamespace);
        OMNamespace namespaceWSU = factory.createOMNamespace(
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "wsu");

        OMAttribute attribute = factory.createOMAttribute("Id", namespaceWSU, "SOAI_req_SOAI");
        usernameTokenElement.addAttribute(attribute);
        securityBlock.addChild(usernameTokenElement);

        OMElement usernameElement = factory.createOMElement("Username", securityNamespace);
        usernameElement.setText(username);
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(usernameElement);

        OMElement passwordElement = factory.createOMElement("Password", securityNamespace);

        attribute = factory.createOMAttribute("Type", null,
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest");
        passwordElement.addAttribute(attribute);
        passwordElement.setText(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(passwordDigest), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(passwordElement);

        OMElement nonceElement = factory.createOMElement("Nonce", securityNamespace);
        attribute = factory.createOMAttribute("EncodingType", null,
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
        nonceElement.addAttribute(attribute);
        nonceElement.setText(new String(Base64.encodeBase64(nonceBytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(nonceElement);

        OMElement createdElement = factory.createOMElement("Created", securityNamespace);
        createdElement.setText(createdDate);
        usernameTokenElement.addChild(createdElement);
    }
```

**Edit 1**

So what i tried we are using our own Docker file to create image and here is the contents

```
FROM wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u232-b09-slim
COPY /lib/* $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/lib/
COPY /carFiles/api_common-20.11.0-SNAPSHOT.car $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
COPY /carFiles/api_impl-20.11.0-SNAPSHOT.car $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
COPY /carFiles/api-20.11.0-SNAPSHOT.car $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/
```

After this build will be use to deploy into the Docker+Kubernetes Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't change the Java version in runtime. Hence, we have to build a new image with the required Java version. You can either use the existing `Dockerfile` and modify it to build an image from the scratch or you can build a new image on top of the `wso2/wso2mi` and change the Java version in it.

For reference, [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/tree/v4.0.0/distribution/src/docker-distribution) is the `Dockerfile` used to build the `wso2/wso2mi` images.

---

#### Update

Given below is a sample `Dockerfile` and the steps used to build the image with Java 8 locally

- Update the existing [CentOS](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/blob/v4.0.0/distribution/src/docker-distribution/centos/Dockerfile) `Dockerfile` with Java 8 base image

  ```
  FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:x86_64-centos-jre8u242-b08
  ```
- Download and place the `wso2mi-4.0.0` in the same directory where the `Dockerfile` is placed. Rename the `wso2mi-4.0.0` to `wso2mi`
- Execute the following command to build the image

  ```sh
  docker build -t <tag-name> . --build-arg MICROESB_VERSION=4.0.0
  ```
- Once it is built, start a container locally to verify everything is working. Then, push the image to a private/public Docker repository and refer that in the K8s to pull it

  ```sh
  docker run -d --name <container-name> <image-name>
  ```
- Additionally, you can perform the `exec` command to go inside the container and verify the Java version

  ```sh
  docker exec -it <container-name> sh
  ```

---

#### Update 2

As you are using the existing `wso2/wso2mi` image to build your own image, you can follow a similar approach as following to install and configure the Java 8.

The given approach downloads the Java 8 binary from GitHub and configures the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables. Find a sample `Dockerfile` below

```
FROM wso2/wso2mi:4.0.0
# FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk8:jdk8u232-b09-slim

# Perform COPY artifacts
COPY /lib/* $WSO2_SERVER_HOME/lib/
...

# Download and configure Java 8
RUN \
    wget -O jdk8.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz; \
    mkdir -p ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8; \
    cd ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8; \
    tar -xf ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/jdk8.tar.gz --strip-components=1; \
    export PATH=${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8/bin:$PATH; \
    rm ${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/jdk8.tar.gz;

ENV JAVA_HOME=${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8 \
    PATH=${WORKING_DIRECTORY}/openjdk-8/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: So i am already using the DockerFile their only if i will declare different java version ,will it override the version used by wso2 in its own Dokcerfile?

Comment: Yes, you can change the Java Version and the relevant paths and build the image.

Comment: Is this is tested somewhere i tried but its failing with error ..`Back-off restarting failed container`

Comment: Were you able to run and check the container locally in your environment? Can you describe the pod and check the events, what is causing to rollback?

Comment: I edited my question and added Docker File details

Comment: Updated the answer with `Update 2` instructing how to modify your `Dockerfile`. Hope this helps to solve your issue

Comment: wget: bad address 'github.com'
tar: can't open '/home/wso2carbon/jdk8.tar.gz': No such file or directory
rm: can't remove '/home/wso2carbon/jdk8.tar.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: this command directly working ` wget -O jdk8.tar.gz https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz; `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234335/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-athiththan).

Comment: Can we make a image over java and then update wso2?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use the base template given [here](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/tree/v4.0.0/distribution/src/docker-distribution) to construct a new image with the relevant Java version and WSO2 updates.

Comment: Can you please tell Registry Concept?